# Google maps API key error - Angular - ApiProjectMapError

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key, angular-google-maps

I have an angular application where I have implemented Angular Google Maps (AGM) successfully.

I have added the `<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-map>` in the component.
The typescript file has title, lat and lng:
`title: string = 'My first AGM project'; lat: number = 51.678418;lng: number = 7.809007;`

And the css file has the `height: 300px;` property.
All of this is ok.

**The problem is the Google API key.**

When I opet the page, I can see the map for 1 sec and then I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC0wk.jpg):

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: ApiProjectMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-project-map-error

Which, when I look at the documentation, it says:

> Either the provided API key or the API project with which it is associated, could not be resolved. This error may be temporary. If this error message persists you may need to get a new API key or create a new API project.

I have created two API keys and in both cases I get the same error.
This is how the Credentials page looks like:

[image]

When I open the API key page, this is what I have:
[image]

Note:

- The API is enabled. (As you can see in the screenshot)
- There are no restrictions on the key. (No application restrictions and no API restrictions)
- The yellow warning next to the name of the api (screenshot 1), just
  says "This API key is unrestricted. To prevent unauthorized use and
  quota theft, restrict your key to limit how it can be used."
- I have imported the AgmCoreModule in the app.module.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your Google Map Javascript API is enabled or not?

Add below code to your appModule file

```
AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
   apiKey: 'Your API Key',
}),
```

Also, add into index.html

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&libraries=places&language=en"></script>
```

Comment: Like you see in the screenshot. The API is enabled.
I also have the AgmCoreModule, like I said in the noted.
I added the script to the index.html, but still nothing. Same error.

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out !
I just needed to add libraries in the app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'MY_API_KEY',
      libraries: ['places']
    })
  ]
```